# I can't understand why PDO insert &#39; in place of single quote

Tags: php, pdo

I have to store a string in MySQL db by PDO class, the strange thing is that if the string contains single quote is stored with `&#39;` in the table, for example:

```
ON AIR - Vocalelli: "Jorginho da Pallone d'Oro"
```

is stored as

```
ON AIR - Vocalelli: "Jorginho da Pallone d&#39;Oro"
```

I use prepared statements ...

```php
<?php

namespace MyApp;

use \PDO;

class Db extends PDO {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $host = '***';
        $dbname = '***';
        $username = '***';
        $password = '***';

        parent::__construct("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
    }

    public function insertArticles($articles) 
    {
        echo '<h1>Array Stored</h1>';

        foreach($articles as $article) 
        {
            echo $article['text'] . '<br>';

            $data = [
                'href' => $article['href'],
                'image' => $article['image'],
                'text' => $article['text'],
                'date' => $article['date'],
                'cover' => $article['cover']
            ];

            $sql = "
            INSERT IGNORE INTO `articles`(`href`, `image`, `text`, `date`, `cover`) 
            VALUES (:href, :image, :text, :date, :cover) 
            ";

            $stmt = $this->prepare($sql);

            //$text = str_replace('&#39;', "'", );

            $stmt->bindParam(':href', $article['href'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':image', $article['image'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindValue(':text', $article['text'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':date', $article['date'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':cover', $article['cover'], PDO::PARAM_STR);             


            $stmt->execute();
        }

        echo '<h1>Fetch All</h1>';

        $sql = "
        SELECT * FROM articles 
        ";

        $stmt = $this->prepare($sql);  
        
        $stmt->execute();
        
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
        foreach($rows as $row)
        {
            echo $row['text'] . '<br>';
        }
    }   
}
```

scraping code

```
// set chars encoding
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_http_output('UTF-8');

// assuming you installed from Composer:
require "vendor/autoload.php";

// parser
use PHPHtmlParser\Dom;
use PHPHtmlParser\Options;
$dom = new Dom;

// carbon
use Carbon\Carbon;
$carbon = new Carbon;
$carbon::setlocale('it');

// whoops
/*
$whoops = new \Whoops\Run;
$whoops->prependHandler(new \Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler);
$whoops->register();
*/

// utils
use \MyApp\Utils;
$utils = new Utils;

// thumbs
use \MyApp\Thumbs;
$thumbs = new Thumbs;

// database
use \MyApp\Db;
$db = new Db;

// mailer
use \MyApp\Mailer;
$mailer = new Mailer;

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// napolimagazine.com
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

$url = 'https://www.napolimagazine.com';

if($utils::checkUrl($url)) 
{

    try {

        $dom->loadFromUrl($url);

        // images

        $images = $dom->find('.layout_Home_Big_box_correlati')[0]->find('li');

        foreach($images as $image) 
        {
            $coverImages[] = str_replace('86/61', '490/305', $image->find('img')->getTag()->getAttribute('src')->getValue());
        }

        $dom->loadFromUrl($url . '/in-primo-piano');

        $covers = $dom->find('.contenitor_section_center')[0]->find('.layout_Home_4');

        foreach($covers as $cover)
        {

            $a = $cover->find('a')[0];
            $href = $a->getTag()->getAttribute('href')->getValue(); 
            $image = str_replace('140/80', '490/305', $cover->find('img')->getTag()->getAttribute('src')->getValue());
            $text = substr($a->find('.layout_Home_4_title')[0]->text, 14);
            $string = substr($a->find('.layout_Home_4_title')[0]->text, 0, 11);
            $date = Carbon::createFromFormat('j.m H:i', $utils::cleanString($string))->toDateTimeString();
            $diff = Carbon::createFromFormat('j.m H:i', $utils::cleanString($string))->diffForHumans(['parts' => 2]);

            // add data to array

            if(in_array($image, $coverImages))
            {
                $articles[] = 
                [
                    'href' => $url . $href,
                    'image' => $image,
                    'text' => $text,
                    'date' => $date,
                    'diff' => $diff,
                    'cover' => true,    
                ];
            }

        }

        // items

        $dom->loadFromUrl($url);

        $items = $dom->find('.contenitor_section_center')[0]->find('.layout_Home_3');

        foreach($items as $item)
        {

            $a = $item->find('a')[0];
            $href = $a->getTag()->getAttribute('href')->getValue();
            $text = strip_tags(html_entity_decode($a->text));
            $image = str_replace('170/150', '490/305', $item->find('img')->getTag()->getAttribute('src')->getValue());
            $string = $item->find('.layout_Home_Big_box_description')[0]->find('span')[0]->text;
            $date = Carbon::createFromFormat('j.m H:i', $utils::cleanString($string))->toDateTimeString();
            $diff = Carbon::createFromFormat('j.m H:i', $utils::cleanString($string))->diffForHumans(['parts' => 2]);

            // add data to array

            $articles[] = 
            [
                'href' => $url . $href,
                'image' => $image,
                'text' => $text,
                'date' => $date,
                'diff' => $diff,
                'cover' => false,    
            ];

        }

    } catch (Error $e) {
    
        $mailer->sendMail($utils::betweenString($url, '.', '.'), $e->getMessage());
        
    }

}
```

Comment: What does `$this->quote()` do?

Comment: Hi Aynber, it was an error of mine ... i edited my question

Comment: Sounds like you're encoding the string into html entities at some point. How are you populating the variables you're inserting? And where exactly do you see `&#39;` instead of the quote? In some management tool like PHPMyAdmin/MySQLWorkbench or through PHP when you read and output the data?

Comment: where is $text being set? what does it look like before you save it to the database

Comment: @MagnusEriksson the string came from a webpage parsed, printing the string looks like without html code, i see the string with html markup in MySQL table,

Comment: @Zachary before saving looks like plain text

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no idea what _"the string came from a webpage parsed"_ means. Is it a form? Then show us the form and how you fetch those values and store them in your variables (the ones you're using in your `bindParam()` methods in PHP) _"i see the string with html markup in MySQL table"_ - _How_ are you seeing the html markup in MySQL table? Are you fetching the data using PHP and echo it on the web page? Are you looking at the data through some application? We need _specifics_ (all relevant code) or we won't have a clue what's actually going on.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i make a parsing of a URL, then i extract some html elements from web page and then store the elements in array, and finally i store the array values in database and when i print the array before INSERT query it looks like good: i see the markup when i read table data by a MySQL client (like Php my admin)

Comment: obviously i can solve making a str_replace before INSERT query but i think it would not be necessary

Comment: Please _show us_ the code instead of just describing it. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68288459/edit) your question to include _all_ relevant code. Have you tried to SELECT the data in PHP and checked what it looks like, so it's not just PHPMyAdmin that encodes the data when it displays it in their UI?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson sorry but this is my first question on Stack ;)

I have tried to make a SELECT QUERY and this is the result
[link](http://alessandroavallone.it/parser-dom/parser-dom.php)

i edited my code and i posted the entire script

Comment: So based on the comments here, the string _always_ had HTML entities. Nothing is adding them. You're scraping a website and not decoding them.

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with PDO, and shouldn't be fixed in the code you shared. The code that scrapes the website should clean up the data before sending it to your `insertArticles` function.

Comment: @Evert when i scrape the webpage and than print the result it's all OK,
infact [here](https://alessandroavallone.it/parser-dom/app.php) you can see the list of html elements scraped from various webpage stored in the array, and the fetch of the result of the query that display the array stored in database: and it looks like everything is fine but when i read MySQL table i can see d&#39; instead of single quote

the code of the scraping is long, cause it scrape a few webpages 
(all of scraping are pretty much the same,)
i edited the original post so you can see scraping code

``

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i added all the code ;)

Comment: @AlessandroAvallone of course they wouldn't show in a HTML page, because they are HTML entities. You can however see &#39; when you 'view source' on your page.

Comment: of course i know &#39; entity: i use DevTools of Chrome and it was supposed to show source code :P
however i added a super easy str replace and go on ;)